# VBScript to read from individual cells in Excel, Automation or ADODB?

Tags: excel, vbscript, automation, adodb

not a coder, and first time asking a question... so go easy please!  Using VBScript here in an application for on air graphics.

I have two methods that work for reading data from an excel spreadsheet.  I think they are called Automation and ADODB Connection.

I can get both to work, but here's the catch: Automation is slower, but it can read individual cells easily.  ADODB is super fast, but I can't point to individual cells, only columns.  Does that make sense?

I would love to be able to use ADODB to read individual cells.  Am I crazy?

Here is my code:

AUTOMATION (works, but take 10 seconds):

```
Dim SelectedboxSpreadsheet

    'InputBox: ask for spreadsheet
    Dim shell : Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Dim boxSpreadsheet : Set boxSpreadsheet = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select box Spreadsheet:", &H4000, "%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe")
    SelectedboxSpreadsheet = boxSpreadsheet.self.path

Dim objExcel
Dim currentWorksheet
Dim Cells

Sub OpenExcelSheet(SheetNumber)
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Workbooks.open SelectedboxSpreadsheet, false, true
    Set currentWorksheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetNumber)
    Set Cells = currentWorksheet.Cells 
End Sub

Sub CloseExcelSheet()
    objExcel.Workbooks.Close
    objExcel.Quit
    Set currentWorkSheet = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    Set Cells = Nothing
End Sub


Call OpenExcelSheet("box")

    TrioCmd("page:set_property H111 " & (Cells(2,2).Value))
    TrioCmd("page:set_property I111 " & (Cells(2,8).Value))
    TrioCmd("page:update")

Call CloseExcelSheet
```

And ADODB (works, but can't read specific cells, have to format the spreadsheet like a table):

```
Dim SelectedSpreadsheetFromTxt

Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file =fso.OpenTextFile("C:\ProgramData\vizrt\Trio\WorldCupDrawSpreadsheetPath.txt")
Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
line = file.ReadLine
Loop
file.Close

SelectedSpreadsheetFromTxt = line

dim objConnection, objRecordSet

set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &_
"Data Source=" & SelectedSpreadsheetFromTxt & ";" &_
"Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes; IMEX=1"";"

dim A1name,A1tri,A2name,A2tri,A3name,A3tri,A4name,A4tri

objRecordSet.Open "SELECT * FROM [Trio Data Group A$]", objConnection

Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
   A1name = objRecordSet.Fields.Item("A1name")
   A1tri = objRecordSet.Fields.Item("A1tri")
   A2name = objRecordSet.Fields.Item("A2name")
   A2tri = objRecordSet.Fields.Item("A2tri")
   A3name = objRecordSet.Fields.Item("A3name")
   A3tri = objRecordSet.Fields.Item("A3tri")
   A4name = objRecordSet.Fields.Item("A4name")
   A4tri = objRecordSet.Fields.Item("A4tri")

   TrioCmd("page:set_property 0006 " & A1tri)
   TrioCmd("page:set_property 0007 " & A2tri)
   TrioCmd("page:set_property 0008 " & A3tri)
   TrioCmd("page:set_property 0009 " & A4tri)

   TrioCmd("page:set_property 0401 " & A1name)
   TrioCmd("page:set_property 0411 " & A2name)
   TrioCmd("page:set_property 0421 " & A3name)
   TrioCmd("page:set_property 0431 " & A4name)

objRecordSet.MoveNext
Loop
```

Anyway, this seems like a shot in the dark, but any advice would be appreciated... thanks!!!

Answer (score -2):

You should just use the Automation because even though it takes 10 seconds it works better

Comment: Why is it better? you should explain your answer in a more descriptive way.